# Swift Type<Type> Meaning

Tags: swift

In Swift I have seen types written as `Response<Person>` or something like that. What are the differences of that vs `Person`? What does it mean when you have `Type<Type>`? Is this called something specific in Swift?

Comment: Please read about [Generics](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html) in the Swift book.

Answer (score 0):

Try to imagine price for something. It could be money, some items, or anything yo want.
As far you can program object Price with nessesary methods for this class, you must not specify which value you will work with. 
Price says you can define Price with different types of value of Price: Price, Price, Price
For example Array allows to keep Double numbers inside, Array  – strings etc.
If you class as:

```
Class Price<T>{
   init(amount:T){}
}
```

You can init

```
let priceForDance = Price(amount: someWoodenBlocs)
let priceForWork = Price(amount: someDollars)
let priceForFamily = Price(amount: Hours(5)
```

Now priceForDance, priceForWork and priceForFamily are different types created by one piece of code.

Comment: Don't confuse protocols and generics. While they can be used together, they don't have to be. You can create perfectly good generics without protocols.

Comment: Removed protocol. Too complicated.